# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray). when giving array of arrays

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, text-classification

I try to classify words. I represent each word with 3 arrays : 1 for the previous word, 1 for the current word, 1 for the following word.
So my input data is an numpy.array of numpy.arrays. By trying to fit my model

```
model.fit(np.asarray(bddX, dtype=object),np.asarray(list(dictXY.values()), dtype=object), epochs=20, batch_size=100)
```

I get the following error : `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).`

I have tried to provide the words as lists, tuple, and as numpy.arrays. This is how I construct bddX

`bddX=[]`

```
for i in range(len(X_train)):
    triple=[]
    triple.append(np.array(dictX.get(X_train[i-1]),dtype=float))
    triple.append(np.array(dictX.get(X_train[i]),dtype=float))
    if(i< len(X_train)-1):
        triple.append(np.array(dictX.get(X_train[i+1]),dtype=float))
    bddX.append(np.asarray(triple))
```

X_train provides the array representing the word.
It works when I give an array of 1 array but not an array of 3 arrays.
Has anyone tried to do this and saw it through ?

Comment: This comes up often.  Usually it's because the component arrays differ in shape.

Comment: Indeed my first word is represented only by 2 arrays and the last one too. Do you think that's the problem ?

Comment: That was indeed the problem, thank you